# Chromium busy indicator

Tags: javascript, browser, chromium

Chromium *sometimes* shows that my angularjs application is busy, although it isn't:

- Instead of  the favicon, it shows a spinner.
- Instead of the reload circular arrow, it shows a cross.

The application is idle, reacts quickly, and I can't see any activity in the devtools: There's no outstanding request and the timeline has zero events. The computed is idle.

Clicking on the cross (which  stops loading), does nothing at all (and the cross does not change to a circular arrow). Nor does clicking on the stop icon in the source code debugger do anything.

Any chance to find out what's causing this?

Comment: `Any chance to find out what's causing this?` you have a better chance than anyone else ... any clues in the web developer tools?

Comment: @JaromandaX As I wrote, there's nothing there... absolutely nothing.